# Why do I keep getting this error on Postgreql psql: /lib64/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, centos, webmin

Updated: Someone mentioned below this is a duplicate of this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269473/what-does-psql-usr-pgsql-11-lib-libpq-so-5-no-version-information-available Well mine is on centos and  Below is what shows when I use: rpm -qa|grep postgres command.
postgresql-10.6-1.module_el8.0.0+15+f57f353b.x86_64
postgresql-server-10.6-1.module_el8.0.0+15+f57f353b.x86_64

I have been having these errors lately, I am accessing the server remotely and I have tried to search for ways to rectify this, yet I have not gotten a concrete way to do this: some people advised to reinstall the PostgreSQL but I am not too sure about this; As it stands now I don't really know what works here so I have decided to ask this: below is the error from the console;

```
[postgres@gma ~]$ psql
psql: /lib64/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)
psql: /lib64/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)
psql (10.6)
Type "help" for help.
```

**When I used this command:** yum list installed | grep postgres

**I got this:** `Modular dependency problems:

Problem 1: conflicting requests

- nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBD-Pg:3.7:8010020200204214655:0d1d6681-0.x86_64
  Problem 2: conflicting requests
- nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBI:1.641:8010020191113222731:16b3ab4d-0.x86_64`

The Modular dependency problem is solved but it still shows the same error: I used this for resolving the modular dependency issue: <
root pass:#  yum module enable perl:5.26

> 

Comment: This is a direct duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/269473/176905

Answer (score -3):

The reason why you are getting such error is because you have not mentioned the **(-h)** Host location of the database server(localhost if running locally) , **(-u)** username for the database access and **(-W)** to ask password in your psql command. After which it would look some what like this:

**$psql -U {username}   -h {host}   -W**

examples:

- $psql -U jack -h localhost:5432 -W
- $psql -U jack -h 54.261.74.39:5432 -W

Worked for me this way.